# Excluding multiple criteria at the end of line

Tags: regex

I am looking for some help with the below regex rules

- Must begin with `Include(`
- Must end with `s)`
- Must not have `)` in the middle
- I would like to exclude results that end `Address)`, `Status)` or
  `Process)`

I've got the first three rules working with the following RegEx:

```
(?=Include\().[^\)]*(s\))
```

But every time I try to improve it to include rule #4 I completely break the RegEx and get no matches.  Here is a link with a sample of what I've got so far, it's currently got 7 matches but there are two false positives that rule 4 would exclude if I were able to implement it so I am only expecting 5 matches: https://regexr.com/4snsb

It should satisfy the below 5 lines:

```
Include(x => x.ClientBuyerAutoCharges)
Include(x => x.ClientContacts)
Include(x => x.ClientContactCommsTypes)
Include(x => x.ClientInspectionValues)
Include(x => x.ClientUnitTypeVATStates)
```

Comment: Try  `Include\([^()]*s\)(?<!Address\)|Status\)|Process\))`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ICEOkj/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, can you please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Include\([^()]*s\)(?<!Address\)|Status\)|Process\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ICEOkj/1)

**Details**

- `Include\(` - a `Include(` text
- `[^()]*`  - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `s\)` - `s)` text
- `(?<!Address\)|Status\)|Process\))` - a negative lookbebind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is `Address)`, `Status)` or `Process)`.